# Is it possible to set the height of certain static UITableView cells and not all of them when conditions are met?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, static, cells

I have a UITableView with static cells and through a search the cells that don't match the search are hidden. Is there a way to set the row height of the cells that are hidden. I have tried to use if statements but they end up changing all the cells in the tableview and not the hidden ones.

Basically I was wondering that when a cell is hidden if its row height can then be changed as well

EDIT
Sorry I was away from my code when I posted the question

At the moment the I have the UITableView with static cells and a search bar with search display controller. 
The code is below for the search bar

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UITableViewCell) NSArray *cells;
@property(nonatomic) CGFloat rowHeight;




@implementation tableViewController

@synthesize searchBar;  
@synthesize cells;  
@synthesize rowHeight;  






- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
for(UITableViewCell *cell in self.cells) 
{
    UILabel *label = cell.textLabel;
    NSString *text = label.text;
   cell.hidden = searchText.length != 0 && ([text rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location == NSNotFound);

    if (cell.hidden) {


        rowHeight = 10;

    }


       }

}
```

This is what hides the cells that don't match. The problem i'm having is that when the cells are hidden they take up space in the display and to save space and to make things look better I want the hidden cells to be set to height of 0 OR 1 to save the space (10 is used as an example until I could get it to work) and to make everything line up.
When the search bar is cancelled or clicked from it sets all the row heights back to 44. What happens with this code is that all the cells are set to 10 and not just the hidden ones.

Comment: post some code, so we understand what you already tried.

Comment: Why do you need to set the height of hidden rows?

Comment: I have updated the above post with my code

Answer (score 0):

Row height is controlled via

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

So when you hide a row, however you are doing this, you could reload that particular row. The method above could check a BOOL on the cell and use that to determine the height returned.

However there is another way to achieve what you want:

Here is an example of how I filter a table. I have a standard UISearchBar at the top of my table which calls this method with the search text: (some of the method calls are part of my project.. but you should get the idea)

Basically, it gives the tableview a different array of data, and then reloads the table. If the search is cancelled, or the searchText is blank - it will get my original tableData.

```
- (void) performSearchWithText:(NSString *)searchText {
    [super performSearchWithText:searchText];
    if ([searchText length] > 0) {
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title contains[cd] %@", searchText]; 
        NSArray *filteredArray = [[self.setListController sets] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
        self.tableData = [NSArray arrayWithArray:filteredArray];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    } else {
        self.tableData = [self.setListController sets];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

This works well for me.

EDIT: or...........

Now, if you want to continue doing it the way you are doing.. you could try this.... it doesn't look too efficient though, but you only have 32 cells, so it should be fine. Ideally though, you want to separate the data and view - so you search the data and tell the view to update. Currently you are searching text in the view.

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {    
    [self.hiddenCells removeAllIndexes];
    for(UITableViewCell *cell in self.cells) {
        UILabel *label = cell.textLabel;
        NSString *text = label.text;
        BOOL shouldHide = searchText.length != 0 && ([text rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location == NSNotFound);
        if (shouldHide) {
            [self.hiddenCells addIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell]];
       }         
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}


- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (self.hiddenCells containsIndex:indexPath) {
        return 0.0f;
    } else {
        return 40.0f;
    }
}
```

You also need to create this property: @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableIndexSet *hiddenCells;

Comment: Are you using this with static cells?

Comment: No, but what difference does that make? How many of these static cells are you using?

Comment: Just curious, in the project there are 35 static cells and i'm struggling to make your code work for my project. Can you show anymore information.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help, i'm getting two errors from the code. Both are 
    
"Incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending 'NSIndexPath *__strong' to parameter of type 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned int');"
    
I'm still learning objective C so I might be stupid at times but your really helping me out, thanks again